# Animating the <body> background using CSS and skrollr.js

Tags: javascript, css, animation, skrollr

I would like to animate the `background-position` CSS property of the `<body>` tag using `skrollr.js`. I want it to slightly move the background image up as the page scrolls to give it a little spice. However, using this...

```
data-0="background-position: 0px 0px;" data-1000="background-position: 0px -250px;"
```

...isn't working.

I tried using a `<div>` to accomplish the feat (animating its `background-position`), but that doesn't give me the effect I am looking for. When I animate the `background-property` of the `<div>`, the `background-position` works correctly; but once the `<div>` scrolls out of sight, whatever is behind the `div` become visible, which I don't want. Any suggestions?

Comment: can't reproduce http://jsbin.com/sobuwopo/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what was causing the issue.  I had my CSS written like this:

```
background: url(/images/mainBG.jpg) no-repeat center fixed!important;
```

I needed to remove the "!important" and it worked like a charm. But... Now I've noticed another issue (Which I will post the answer here if I get resolved).  I am implementing this into a 4.0 C# .net website with MasterPages (see this in action here: brugrill.ntxdesigns.com).  Considering that all of the .aspx pages will be of different lengths, I can't use the skrollr.js within the MasterPage as it sets the height of the pages based off of what you put in the "data-" property so if the page is longer than the pixel position of the "data-" property (say the page is 5000 pixels and the property of the "data-" is 1000) the background scrolling stops before the page is finished scrolling.  If the "data-" property is longer than the pixel length of the page, the page keeps scrolling after it should have stopped which looks bad (as you can see by my link above).  I am hoping I can use the codebehind with a `this.Page.Master.FindControl` to find the body control tag and modify the "data-" properties to the values I need.

Is there a way through javascript, jquery or otherwise to get the current pixel length of the page and use that value in the "data-" property?  Then I wouldn't have to hardcode this data and if the page grows, the value grows.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: It would be better to post your follow-up question as a new question so that its answers don't get confounded with the ones here.